# Trigonometric Equation.1

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve 
>   $$\sin(3x+28^\circ)=\cos(2x-13^\circ)$$
>   $x\in (0,90^\circ)$

$$3x+28^\circ+2x-13^\circ=90^\circ$$
$$5x+15^\circ=90^\circ$$
$$5x=75^\circ$$
$$x=15^\circ$$
Or
$$3x+28^\circ-2x+13^\circ=90^\circ$$
$$x=49^\circ$$
But the answer is
$$x=87^\circ$$
satisfies the equation , my question is whats the procedure to get this value ?

Comment: Did you mean $\sin(3x+28)=\cos(2x-13)$?

Comment: Please use brackets to specify whether it is $(\sin 3x)+18$ or $\sin (3x+28)$. Also explicitly tell that the argument is in degrees, not radians.

Comment: Now you've added $x = (0,\frac {\pi}2) $. Please do not switch between radians and degrees.

Comment: Sorry , i did not notice this switching

Answer (score 2):

Your notation is a bit messy... It looks like you're using degrees (instead of radians; although you give the interval in radians) but there are a lot of parentheses missing. You probably mean:

$$\sin\left(3x+28^\circ\right)=\cos\left(2x-13^\circ\right)$$

Now since $\cos\left(90^\circ-x\right)=\sin(x)$, you can write:

$$\cos\left(90^\circ-\left(3x+28^\circ\right)\right)=\cos\left(2x-13^\circ\right)$$

Simplify:

$$\cos\left(62^\circ-3x\right)=\cos\left(2x-13^\circ\right)$$

Now use $\cos\alpha = \cos\beta \iff \alpha = \pm \beta + k \cdot 360^\circ$ (with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$), solve for $x$ and then select the solutions in the required interval.

Comment: This procedure is the same i mentioned ,it leads to two solutions x = 15 , x=49 but x=87 does not be produced @StackTD

Comment: It's not the same at all. You had $\sin(a) = \cos(b) \Rightarrow a\pm b = 90^\circ$ when it should be $a+b = 90^\circ + k\cdot 360^\circ = 90^\circ, 450^\circ, \dots$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \sin(3x + 28^\circ) = \cos(2x - 13^\circ) $$

$$ \sin(3x + 28^\circ) = \cos(90^\circ - 2x + 13^\circ) $$

$$ 3x + 28^\circ = 90^\circ- 2x + 13^\circ + n\cdot 360^\circ $$

$$ 5x + 15^\circ = 90^\circ + n\cdot 360^\circ $$

$$ x = 15^\circ + n\cdot 72^\circ $$

Since $0^\circ \le x \le 90^\circ$, this gives $0 \le n \le 1$, or $n = 0,1$